# Gensim doc2vec most similar gives unsupported operand type(s) error

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, gensim, word-embedding, doc2vec

I am using a pre-trained  doc2vec model, when I try to find out most similar document to that of my sample document. It gives me  unsupported operand type(s) error.

```
from gensim.models import Doc2Vec

filename = "doc2vec.bin"
doc1 =["This is a sample document."]

model = Doc2Vec.load(filename)

inferred_vector = model.infer_vector(doc1)

sims = model.docvecs.most_similar(positive=[inferred_vector],topn=1)

print(sims)
```

This gives me following error

```
 File "D:\doc2vectest.py", line 10, in <module>
    sims = model.docvecs.most_similar(positive=[inferred_vector],topn=1)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py", line 1667, in most_similar
    self.init_sims()
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py", line 1630, in init_sims
    self.vectors_docs_norm = _l2_norm(self.vectors_docs, replace=replace)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py", line 2346, in _l2_norm
    dist = sqrt((m ** 2).sum(-1))[..., newaxis]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your pre-trained model isn't compatible with the version of `gensim` in your environment. Where did the model originate?

(Separately: `infer_document()` requires a list-of-tokens, *not* a string. And, those tokens should have been preprocessed in exactly the same was as whatever training data was used to train the model.)